# How to group and filter in python pandaas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df_select = { 'ISIN': ['x123', 'x345' , 'x745' , 'x743', 'x984'], 
              'ISSUER': ['AH'  ,'BZ' , 'NP', 'BZ', 'AH'], 
              'Opt': [5,4,3,2,1],
             'Rating': [5,4,3,4,6],
              'control': [1,1,1,1,1]}
df= pd.DataFrame(df_select)
```

I want to filter those records where the sum of rating is larger than 6

```
x = df.groupby('ISSUER')['Rating'].sum()
x = x[x>6]
```

How do I make the final selection on the pandas (and in general, is this the best way to do this?)

```
df[df['ISSUER'] isin (x.index)]
```

is not working

Comment: your code should wok just fine , isn't that the output you want? show us your desired output as well

Comment: Yes.. but i cant use it in a selection: df[df['ISSUER'] isin (x.index)]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of aggregating with `sum` you need to use `transform` with `sum`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('ISSUER')['Rating'].transform('sum').gt(6)]
```

---

```
   ISIN ISSUER  Opt  Rating  control
0  x123     AH    5       5        1
1  x345     BZ    4       4        1
3  x743     BZ    2       4        1
4  x984     AH    1       6        1
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to create a resulting dataframe with the complete information of the records with a sum rating larger than 6.  In other words, I'm assuming your desired output is:

```
  ISIN ISSUER  Opt  Rating  control
0  x123     AH    5       5        1
1  x345     BZ    4       4        1
3  x743     BZ    2       4        1
4  x984     AH    1       6        1
```

Working under this assumption you could use the following:

```
new_df = df.loc[df['ISSUER'].isin(x.index.tolist())]
```

You can modify the resulting indexes if you would like with:

```
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```